# My *ngIf statement has problems

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to list all data from my firebase database where the logged in facebook user's email address is the same as the email found in the database:
[image]

The following code is not working, lots of formatting issues, no idea how should i rewrite this

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of fogasadatok; let i = index">
    <ion-card *ngIf="{{item.useremail}}=={{navParams.data.facebookemail}}">

        <img src="{{item.keplink}}"/>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
              {{item.datum}} - Ponty
            </ion-card-title>
          <p>

            Egyéb:
          </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

Comment: Try *ngIf="{{item.useremail == navParams.data.facebookemail}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need interpolation (`{{}}`) for structural directives like `*ngFor` or `*ngIf`. Interpolation is only needed when you want to bind to a value that needs to be stringified for rendering in the DOM (like `item.keplink`). The expression for your `*ngIf` should look as follows:

```
*ngIf="item.useremail === navParams.data.facebookemail"
```